# is it on topic to ask for a refutation of a source you trust?

Tags: discussion

I asked [this question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/31742/was-the-protestant-reformation-the-work-of-a-few-oligarchs) not (merely) to pick a fight but because I really want to know whether there *is* a refutation of Hilaire Bellocs rather astounding claims before I go off and believe they are true.  That, I believe is the point of inquiry and the exact point of this site.

I know the question should be reopened and I know it will after it gets a fair look at because I know the ethos and point of this website. But, I'd like to encourage more asking if questions based off of things people read that just either seem contrary to common sense or contrary to the norm.. I think that's where we can each do the most good.)))

Comment: Maybe you should also ask what evidence there is to support Bellocs' claims ;)

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I think that the phrasing of the question as a "looking for a refutation of a trusted source" question does not affect whether or not the question is itself off-topic. The reason behind that is whether or not it is on topic should depend on *what* the underlying question is, not *why* the question is being asked.

For example, a "Is X a sin?" question is off topic, regardless of where you've heard it from or why you're asking. If a trusted source says it is a sin, a question looking for reasons why it isn't is still off topic, and vice versa.

Comment: I gotcha, but I think you're wrong those "is X as sin" questions are valid if who you heard it from is a scholar or a gentleman within a particular doctrinal framework which obviously sets the tone for the answers.  Here, I think you have to do a little more than assume a casual answerer knows you're only talking about Joanna Southcoteites though.  But tagging [tag:Joanna-Southcotism] ought to be sufficient.  I've found it to be insufficent in questions past though...  You really have to say "According to Joanna Southcote, is neo-platonism a sin according to Joanna Southcote"

Comment: @PeterTurner Unless I'm reading them wrong, the help pages and flagging dialog go out of their way to say that "Is X a sin?" questions are off topic.

Comment: yes, I think you're reading it too literally. You can ask anything you want so long as it falls within a doctrinal framework and it's personal (pastoral) advice.  It has to be answerable, objectively and no one's answer should have to compete with another's answer just because the OP didn't agree with the religious slant of the answerer.   It saves everyone from wasting their time.

Comment: Alright, if you don't like that specific example, my belief is that you ought to be able to phrase the underlying question without mentioning the specific source you're trying to refute or even that you're trying to refute a source (it provides context, but having it or not having it doesn't affect what the question itself is). Whether or not your question is on topic ought to depend on whether this pared down version would be able to stand on its own as an on topic question. Like I said in my answer, what's important should be *what* the question is, not *why* you ask it.

Comment: Oh yeah, you're absolutely right then.  But then, I don't have a question.  What I want to know is was there a contemporary critique of Belloc's claim.  I  really ardently do not want people to go and figure out the answer for themselves because the chances are so great that they'll just start with the premise that they ended with and find 14 facts to justify it without considering the 29 facts that deny it.

Comment: Well, the way I see it, your underlying "question" would've been "Is there evidence to support <opposite of Belloc's claim>?" That being said, you do bring up a good point; it's much better to see both sides of the picture. It sounds like the question you *really* wanted to ask was looking for evidence about the topic itself, with Belloc's claim on one side, and any "refutation" would be a different side (and there need not be only 2 sides)

Comment: That question would be "Is there evidince to support the origins of the Protestant Reformation as a popular revolt against the evils of the Catholic Church".  Might get a few laughs.  I'll probably do ask it tomorrow.

Comment: "Is X a sin?" is off topic. "Does Organization A teach that X is a sin?" is on topic.